# How to concatenate multiple column values based on a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix of binary values I want to use to return different subsets of values from a vector.

This seems like it would be simple, but I can't do anything to generate the desired result

```
G <- as.matrix(data.frame(a=c(0,0,1,0),b=c(1,1,0,0),c=c(1,0,0,1),d=c(0,1,0,0)))
c <- colnames(G)
> G
     a b c d
[1,] 0 1 1 0
[2,] 0 1 0 1
[3,] 1 0 0 0
[4,] 0 0 1 0
```

The result I want is:

```
[1] "b,c" "b,d" "a"   "c"
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sapply(1:nrow(G), function(i) toString(names(G[i, G[i,] == 1])))
#OR
with(data.frame(which(G == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)),
     unname(sapply(split(colnames(G)[col], row), toString)))
#[1] "b, c" "b, d" "a"    "c"
```

If you have newer version of R, you could also do

```
sapply(asplit(G, 1), function(x) toString(names(x)[x == 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that converts 0 and 1 to `FALSE` and `TRUE` to subset the `colnames`:

```
apply(G, 1, function(x) paste(c[as.logical(x)], collapse = ','))

[1] "b,c" "b,d" "a"   "c"
```